# Is there a css framework with size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get my thing to be half of its current size, but whatever I do isn't working, and it is supposed to be an email footer so it can't be as big as it is. Does anyone know a one?

I am new to web development, and CSS is frustrating. Does ANYONE know how to do this? Here is my current code, I want the box to be half of its size:

https://repl.it/@Will_builder8/My-Thing

Comment: Maybe check out flexbox https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: What about `width: 50%;` in your container, isn't that what your're looking for?

Comment: I think they are asking to be 50% of its current width which you could also do `width = width / 2`?

Comment: `.wrapper {
        object-fit: cover;
        max-width: 50%;
      }` ???

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/WoodenSpeedySystemcall

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).